# Accessing form values from route in controller and model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

In my app.js I'm passing on the request to the router like so

```
app.post('/validateUser', validationRoute)
```

In my route I'd normally do like this, to pass the request on to the controller, and call the appropriate function.

```
router.use('/', validationCon.validateUser)
```

My validateUser which is found in my controller, looks like this

```
module.exports = {

    validateUser: async (req, res) => {
        //const uName = req.body.uName, 
            //pwd = req.body.pwd;        

        const success = await logic.validateUser(uName, pwd);

        if(success) {
            //res.status(201).send('Login accepted');
            res.render('../views/pages/secret')
        }
        else 
            res.status(400).send("Bad confidentials")                    
    }
}
```

The issue I had by doing `router.use('/', validationCon.validateUser)` was that I didn't have the `req` and `res` to pass on to the controller, so these were undefined or null in my controller. So I changed my router to do:

```
router.use('/',  (req, res, next) => {
    
    //console.log("URL from validate: "+req.url, ' req.body: ', req.body)
    username = req.body.username
    pass = req.body.password

    /* Now I want to pass these 2 values on to the controller*/
})

module.exports = router
```

Now I have the `req` and `res` objects in my route, and so I can access the values in the request body. But the issue I have now, is that I don't know how to pass these on to the controller, since I no longer do `router.use('/', validationCon.validateUser)`

How can I do so that I can access the req body in the controller? As you can see in the controller, I am also passing the values from the request body on to the model, so that they can be verified in the database.

I am not sure if this is the best approach of doing it, this is my first nodejs/express application, so I'm all ears if there are suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `req`, `res`, `next` should be available at the controller too.

A better approach is to set the app to `use` routes, and specify `post` \ `get` at the route level.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/routes)